# Is it possible to make the psql \copy see a line inside a csv file as a comment?

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-copy

I'm successfully inserting `csv` files to `postgresql` with the following command:

```
\COPY tablename(col1, col2, col3) FROM '/home/user/mycsv.txt' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ';' NULL AS 'null';
```

However, I'd like to write some metadata inside this `csv` file with data that's repeatable. I know I could create a different file to store this data but I think it'd be a lot more convenient to store this metadata in the same `csv` file where the majority of the data is stored. I imagine a file like the following:

```
-- commented line with some metadata
col1;col2;col3
value;value;value
value;value;value
value;value;value
```

I've tried using `--` `/* /*` and `#` as comments but the `\copy` command fails to import the data when I do that. Is there any way that I can tell the `\copy` `psql` command to see specific lines as comments just so I can insert data with lines that are not a part of the `csv` file? Is it possible?

Comment: No, there is no support for that. `COPY` is not a general purpose, highly configurable loader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the FROM PROGRAM construct to tell something else to filter them out.

```
\COPY tablename(col1, col2, col3) FROM PROGRAM 'egrep -v "^-- " mycsv.txt' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ';' NULL AS 'null'
```

Answer (score 0):

You see how pg_dump does it:

```
pg_dump -d test -U postgres -t orders -a -f test.sql

cat test.sql 

--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 12.3
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 12.3

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

--
-- Data for Name: orders; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

COPY public.orders (order_id, total, order_date, user_id) FROM stdin;
1       100     2020-06-20 00:00:00     1
2       250     2020-06-20 00:00:00     2
\.


--
-- Name: orders_order_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE SET; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.orders_order_id_seq', 2, true);


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--


psql -d test -U postgres -f test.sql 

Null display is "NULL".
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
 set_config 
------------
 
(1 row)

SET
SET
SET
SET
COPY 2
 setval 
--------
      2
(1 row)
```